# How to find the text size for a given rectangle?

Tags: android

I have a doubt. How to find the max text size to a text for a given rectangle. Consider the rectangle width and height is 100,50 respectively. how to find a text size which almost fits the rectangle.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just add a Grid to the rectangle. and Add a TextBlock in the Grid so the any text within the TextBlock would size with the rectangle.

```
<Rectangle>
   <Grid><TextBlock></TextBlock></Grid>
</Rectangle>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you create an [`android.text.Layout.StaticLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/StaticLayout.html) specifying the font and width, and check the height.  You can use this to do a binary search for the text size that best fits your rectangle.

You might want to also check that no individual line has too much padding on one end (think right-to-left language support if you add this check).